# R - Merge rows in a dataframe to fill NAs given a number of identifiers

Tags: r, imputation

Let's say I have a dataframe that includes 5 years of data showing the number of homicides in the 50 biggest cities of all 50 states in America. Also in the dataframe is the population of that city and the number of guns owned. However, in each row there is only one of `population, homicides or guns` (see `df` in example below):

```
> df1 = data.frame(state=1:50, city=rep(1:50, each=50), year=rep(1:5, each=2500), population=sample(1000:200000,12500), homicides=NA, guns=NA)
> df2 = data.frame(state=1:50, city=rep(1:50, each=50), year=rep(1:5, each=2500), population=NA, homicides=sample(1:200,12500,replace=T), guns=NA)
> df3 = data.frame(state=1:50, city=rep(1:50, each=50), year=rep(1:5, each=2500), population=NA, homicides=NA, guns=round((df1$population/sample(2:20,12500,replace=T))))
> df = rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

This resulting dataframe is 25,000 rows longer than it needs to be since each row representing a unique combination of `state, city and year` could include `population, homicide and guns` data, rather than just one. In other words, it could look like this:

```
df.ideal = data.frame(state=1:50, city=rep(1:50, each=50), year=rep(1:5, each=2500), population=sample(1000:200000,12500), homicides=sample(1:200,12500,replace=T), guns=round((df1$population/sample(2:20,12500,replace=T))))
```

Starting with `df`, how can I merge the `population, guns and homicides` data rows to create just one row for each `state, city, year` combination? Therefore resulting in df.ideal

Sadly the solution has to work for unbalanced dataframes as well - in an ideal world it would be great if a warning was presented when a value replaced anything but an NA.

Comment: For independent variables, you mean `year, site, slope, strip` but not layer? What if there are multiple values for each combination of independent?

Comment: You are "imputing" data and you want to do "multiple imputation.  R has several packages with facilities for what you request. You should do some searching.

Comment: @warmoverflow - `Layer` is also an independent variable. In my example only the `carbon` and `nitrogen` columns are dependent variables. There are no multiple values for any combination of independent variables

Comment: @42- I don't want to 'impute' the data but rather transfer the value from one 'cell' to another in the dataframe, replacing NAs of that column. I have done considerable searching and have failed to work out how aggregate or many plyr functions can do what I want for the complex dataset I have. Can you suggest a specific function that would work? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you are imputing data, even if you don't want to call it that. Given your resistance to reasonable advice, my decision if to refrain from further commentary.

Comment: (I) There are multiple approaches that you could take, such as hotdeck imputation, EM, KNN, etc. Please be more specific in what you want to do.  (II) Your example data also doesn't include the richness of relationships that you describe in your question... revise your question to either include this info or remove the commentary about it.

Comment: @Alex thanks for your help. I have changed my example and hopefully this is now clearer. I have researched hotdeck imputation and am not sure how I can apply it to my example. The data that I want are already contained in the dataframe but are simply on numerous different rows that I would like to combine. Sorry about the clarity of my initial phrasing if it was poor

Comment: Your revised question doesn't make sense. Here you have several observations with missing data and you wish to collapse them to a single observation with complete data... This is simply nonsensical... Either you have valid (incomplete) observations, in which case you should impute them all; or you have duplicates which you should remove.